# pgAdmin 4 opens but clicking on server won't show anything (not even error)

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am on MacBook Pro (late 2015). I have a fresh install on macOS Catalina 10.15.2.
I have PostgreSQL 12 which is running with no issues.
Running `which psql` gives me the correct path: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/psql
I can run psql commands with no issues (create user for example).
I have installed pgAdmin 4 (version 4.16). The installation went well with no issues. pgAdmin 4 will open with no issues BUT clicking the server section instead of opening all the users, groups and databases seem to freeze the process (in other words it won't show any).

I have tried to reinstall, restart numerous times. I have downgraded to 4.12 thinking there might be an issue having the latest version. I am getting, however, the same result. I have tried to Google out but haven't seen anyone experiencing a similar issue. Thank you for all your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly I managed to resolve this by chance. Out of desperation, I clicked on Object => Create => Server Group and I have named it Postgres. Clicking again on the Servers in the sidebar opened all the usual databases, Login/Group Roles. If anyone knows why I had to do this and how come it did not work as usual I will be grateful.